Is the Choice of Bravais Lattice for a Crystal Always Unique?
I was wondering if the choice of the Bravais lattice for a given crystal is always unique. It seems to me that, as long as we change the basis, there could be multiple possible choices. For example, diamond is typically described as an FCC lattice with a basis of 2 atoms, but looking at its lattice structure, it also seems that it could be described as a simple cubic lattice with a basis of many atoms (it appears to be 18 atoms when I count them).
If it's true that multiple Bravais lattices can be chosen, I have a question: does the fraction of the band occupied by electrons change based on our choice? The formula for the fraction of the band occupied by electrons is:
$$\frac {s \cdot v} 2$$
​
where
$s$ is the number of atoms in the basis and $v$ is the valence of the atom.
Choosing a basis with more atoms increases the fraction, which seems absurd since the physics of the system should not depend on how we describe it.
One possible explanation I came up with is that while the fraction of the band occupied changes, the band itself also changes because the first Brillouin zone changes with the lattice. This change might compensate for the change in the fraction of the band occupied, ensuring that the physics of the system remains unchanged.

You are correct. Any FCC or BCC lattice can be recast as a simple cubic lattice. What happens, though, is that the simplest looking FCC or BCC Brillouin zone with few bands, will be folded upon itself multiple times, just equivalent to the increase in number of atoms in the basis. In this way, the SC Brillouin zone will be very crowded and complicated. In the end, the physical counting of states will be consistent and correct.
